# How to measure purchases on a site when traffic is coming from a particular source?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking, shopify

We have a website which sells products. Soon we are launching some new featured products and have created a microsite on a subdomain to advertise these products and to push customers to the main site so that they can purchase the products.

We would like to know if there is a way to track how many people land on the microsite (i.e. subdomain of the main site), follow the link through to the main site and then go on to make a purchase.

Is there a way to do this using google analytics or even something in Shopify that will allow us to do this as our main site (the shop) is powered by Shopify?

Thanks

Comment: Build a [campaign URL](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/) . Then track it in the flow between the microsite and the shopping cart. For more information [read this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?visit_id=636868017277405041-2793778685&rd=1) .

Comment: Are you tracking the traffic of this microsite in the same Analytics property, where you track your main site's performance? Or the microsite is not part of your property, and actually works as any third-party referring site?

Comment: the microsite is not part of the property. I think we have sorted it now though. There is an ecommerce setting in google analytics which links it up with shopify so we can track conversions this way! :)

Answer (score 1):

According to shopify, 'Google Analytics' Referral Traffic report shows you which websites generate traffic to your store. For example, if a blog features your business and readers click a link to view your online store, then the blog is listed as a source of traffic to your store.'

Here's a [link](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/reports-and-analytics/google-analytics) to [shopify's guide](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/reports-and-analytics/google-analytics) to setting up and using google analytics.